# Sample from a custom normal probability density function

Tags: python, math, statistics

I am trying to sample from a continuous normal probability function, however I want the percentages contained within each standard deviation to be as follows: -1 std to 1 std = 50%, -2 std to 2 std = 82%, -3 std to 3 std = 96%

Ideally, I want this to be a function I can sample from in Python.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if that's possible, independent of the standard deviation the area -1/+1 std should always be 68%

Comment: To elaborate on the previous comments: a "custom normal" distribution is not a "normal" one. It still has a bell curve, but not the Gaussian bell curve. But having a normal distribution or a specific one is an intrinsic characteristic of the function, so I believe your problem is not how to code it in Python or any other language but how to define it to get the distribution you want

Comment: Thank you all for replying back to me. Yes gimix, I would like to define my own distribution. Any idea how I could do that in Python?

Comment: Do you need the PDF to be smooth? If piecewise constant is good enough, you could simply calculate a uniform random variable `r` and then do inverse transformation sampling. I.e., if `r < 0.5` then you sample `-1 std + 4 * r * std`. If `0.5 <= r < 0.66`, then sample `-2 * std + (r - 0.5) / 0.16 * std` and so on for the other intervals.